# React/NPM dependecy error on create-react-app project

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, http-proxy

I am trying to create a new project and I am running into an npm security issue. 
First I created a new react app using the command `npx create-react-app {app-name}` and then changed the directory into that folder. I tried to run `npm install` (to update all packages), and I get this error:

```
found 2 vulnerabilities (1 low, 1 high) in 1643 scanned packages
2 vulnerabilities require manual review. See the full report for details.
```

I ran `npm audit` as instructed and the generated security report shows the following:

[NPM AUDIT SECURITY REPORT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhcah.png)

at first I thought I had maybe done something incorrectly during the setup, however, I went to a previous project in which there were no dependency errors or errors at all for that matter. I ran `npm install` in the directory of the react app, and sure enough, I got the same issues. Obviously this is going to be a big deal if it is happening to everyone, but in the event that someone is not running into this issue, are the any tips I could get to overcome this error?

Thanks!

Comment: That doesnt work, is just pulls up the report

Comment: should be `npm audit fix` but looks like its' a manual fix within the image